# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph' in jupyter notebook

Tags: tensorflow, keras

---

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute
'get_default_graph'



 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ikoe7.png
```

This codes running jupyter noteebook python3.6 anaconda envs.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM
------------------------------------------
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(1, look_back)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=100, batch_size=256, verbose=2)

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute
'get_default_graph'
```

Comment: What is your question? Please have a look on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can replicate

Comment: What version of Tensorflow are you using? If you're trying to use the latest, this might be relevant: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/12379